# In Bash move files to location, from 2 text files

Tags: linux, bash, foreach, mv

I have a list of files in a text file, one per line, and another text file with the corresponding locations to move the files, one per line.

How can I execute in bash (mv file on (text file1 line 1) to location (on line 1 of text file2))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read from each file separately:

```
while read file1; read file2 <&3; do
   mv -- "$file1" "$file2"
done < file1.txt 3< file2.txt
```